# Abstract member cannot be access directly: Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

I have interface A with implemented method t()

```
interface A{
    fun t() : String{
        return "A"
    }
}
```

And abstract class B

```
abstract class B : A{
     override abstract fun t(): String
}
```

And one class C

```
open class C: A, B(){
    override fun t(): String {
        //return super<A>.t() // getting error
        return super.t() //getting error here 
    }
}
```

I want to call interface function t() but its giving me error **Abstract member cannot be access directly**

**If I remove implementation of A from B its working.**

can anyone explain why?

Comment: There is no implementation of `t()` in `B`, it's `abstract`. What code are you trying to call?

Comment: I want to call A's fun

Comment: as per doc I tried >> return super<A>.t()

Comment: Could you provide a link to that doc?

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#overriding-rules

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/interfaces.html

Comment: You can't do that, since you override the method in `B`, you can not bypass that override. (I can't find a spec reference right now)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no reference in kotlin, but the [Method Invocation Expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12)  `TypeName.super. [TypeArguments] Identifier ( [ArgumentList] )` in java is described exactly in [JLS-15.12.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.3):

**Note**: interface in here is a `class`/ an `interface`.

> If TypeName denotes an **interface**, let `T` be the type declaration immediately enclosing the method invocation. A compile-time error occurs if there **exists a method**, distinct from the compile-time declaration, that **overrides** (§9.4.1) the compile-time declaration from a direct superclass or direct superinterface of `T`.
>
> In the case that a **superinterface** (class `B`) overrides a method declared in a **grandparent interface** (interface `A`), this rule **prevents** the child interface from "skipping" the override by simply adding the grandparent to its list of direct superinterfaces. The **appropriate way to access functionality of a grandparent** is through the **direct superinterface**  (class `B`), and only if that interface chooses to expose the desired behavior. (Alternately, the developer is free to define his own additional superinterface that exposes the desired behavior with a super method invocation.)

So even if the `t()` is a concrete method in class `B`, it also failed in compile time, for example:

```
interface A {
    fun t() = "A"
}

abstract class B : A {
    override fun t() = "B"
}

class C : A, B() {
    //                      v--- error
    override fun t()= super<A>.t();

    //              v--- ok
    fun ok()= super<B>.t();

}
```

Following the rule of the [JLS-15.12.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.3) , you also can't access grandfather interface `A` if you don't let class `C` implements `A` directly, for example:

```
//       v-- grandparent interface A is removed from class C  
class C : B() {    
    //                       v--- can't access the grandparent interface A
    override fun t() = super<A>.t(); 
}
```

An abstract superinterface can re-declare a concrete method in its grandparent interface to an **abstract** method. but you must implements the abstract method in child class, for example:

```
interface GrandParent {
    fun foo() = "bar";
}

interface Parent : GrandParent {
    override fun foo(): String;
}

//     v--- must implements abstract foo() method in Parent interface
class Child : Parent;
```

Answer (score 4):

When `class B` 'called' the `interface A`, it was supposed to implement the function in the interface but didn't do that. Instead, it 'promised' (by using the `abstract` keyword) to leave that implementation to any class that inherits it, to which `interface A` agreed. Now when `class C` came in, it 'called' both `function B` and `interface A` and overrode a `function t()` (a function both interface A and function B have). Now, the question is, which of `function t()` is being overridden? You can't do that and that is why you have your error.

Or using another analogy, `class B` is owing with `interface A`. If `class B` had paid `interface A`, then it can help `class C` settle it's debt with `interface A`, like this:

```
interface A{
    fun t():String{
        return "A"
    }
}

abstract class B :A{
    override fun t():String{
        return "potato"
    }
}

open class C:  A, B(){
    override fun t(): String {
     return super<B>.t()
    }
```

But since that's not the case, `class C` has to settle it's own debt with `interface A` like this:

```
open class C: A {
    override fun t(): String {
     return super.t()
    }

}
```

Or help class B pay his, like this:

```
open class C:  B(){
    override fun t(): String {
     return super.t()
    }

}
```

It can't do both because that will be creating two functions with the same signature. Hope this analogy helped you understand.